# Prevent Xamarin Forms Displayactionsheet from closing on outside touch

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have an  DisplayActionSheet with  two choices; User and Guest. I have to choose any one of these before proceeding to  login page . However, when I click outside the dialog window , the dialog closes. How can I stop this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to use pop-up page in that situation and configure it to not close on background click. There is a simple library which can help you to build popup's https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup, it also available via NuGet.